# What is a more elegant way of showing N significant digits of a calculation?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, significant-digits

I created the following function to show the last six significant digits of a number:

```
private static string ShowSigDigits(long n, int sig)
{
    string[] arr1 = n.ToString().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();

    // reverse the array of string characters 
    Array.Reverse(arr1);
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

    for (int x = 0; x < arr1.Length; x++)
    {
        // get the last sig significant digits (loop is zero-based)
        if (x <= sig-1)
        {
            stringList.Add(arr1[x]);
        }
    }

    stringList.Reverse();

    return(string.Join("", stringList.ToArray()));
}
```

For example, entering 182736734,6 would result in 736734.

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this, and would like some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps n % 1000000?  Or does it have to handle such things as f(12345678000) == 345678000?

Comment: Do you mean x _least_ significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this - [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) is one of the first to come to mind (as does the VB.NET `Strings.Right`).

```
string nString = n.ToString();
return nString.Substring(nString.Length - sig);
```

Comment: Good point, but also you have to check nString.Length - sig >= 0;

Answer (score 1):

Convert (x % 1000000) to string, where % stands for modulo operation.